# Want to add the line from the text box to a list box if it contains a word from words

Tags: vb.net

I Want to add the line from the text box to a list box if it contains a word from words.

This code introduces my result into the textbox, I want it in a textbox line or in a listbox line.

So, `TempTextBox` will have to be a textbox line or a listbox line so I will not create too many textboxes. How can I improve the code?

```
If TextBox1.Lines(i).Contains(word) Then
    found = True
    Dim tempTextBox As TextBox = CType(Me.Controls("CheckVar" & i.ToString), TextBox)
    On Error Resume Next
    If TextBox2.Lines(i).Contains(word) Then
        If tempTextBox.Text.Contains(word) Then
        Else
            tempTextBox.Text = tempTextBox.Text + " " + TxtbValAfterCompar.Text()
        End If
    Else
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Make sure that the "CheckVar" & i control exists before using it. Remove `On Error Resume Next`. Your code should be absolutely fine without it. Also you could change `If tempTextBox.Text.Contains(word) Then` to `If Not tempTextBox.Text.Contains(word) Then` and remove the `Else`Statement

Comment: I want to replace the Checkvar Textbox with the Checkvar line. do you think it could?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: DimTextbox want to be a textbox line or a listbox line. In my case, it's a Textbox.

Comment: So you dont want lots of Checkvar textboxes to store the data, and you want a List(Of String) instead? sure.

Comment: Yes. I want the store to be in a list in the textbox or listbox line.

Comment: Sure you can. Just create a List(Of String) and rewrite your code to use that instead. Have a google for ideas. Sadly writing your code for you is off topic here, but try some things, solve what problems you can, and then if there are some you can't solve, come back here with a question about it :) Ok time for me to go to work. Happy hunting

Comment: Where is i coming from? What are the CheckVar controls? Do TextBox1 and TextBox2 have the same number of lines? Why is TempTextBox a TextBox at all? Should it be just a string?

Comment: If word is in the same line in TextBox1 and TextBox2 then you want to add what?

Comment: This is your third attempt at asking about this code and I still don't know what the outcome is supposed to be.

Comment: So checkvar are several  lots textboxes. I want the tempbox to be a check line or linebox, not more checkvars.